# in R, fix an argument for use the lapply function

Tags: r

This post contains two questions. The first is some related with the second.
First, suppose that I want define one function that receives two arguments: one data frame and one variable(column) and I would like to do some counts or statistics. In first time, I have to determine the variable position. For example, suppose that my two first rows of the df are

```
>  df
  person  age   rent
       1    23  1000
       2    35  1.500
```

and my function is like this

```
> myfun<- function(df, var)
  {
   # determining the variable
   ind<- which(names(df) %in% var )
   # selecting the variable 
   v <- df[,ind]

   # rest of function
   ....


  }
```

I think that it may be more easy... Is there some way to determine v directly?

Second Question: I have a large list of data frames(samples of one population). All data frame have the same variables and one of these variable is the rent. I would like to calculate the mean of the rent variable for each sample and I would like to use the lapply function. For one sample, I can do the following code

```
> mean(sample$rent , na.rm = T)
```

All that I want is do something like this

```
> apply(list, mean( , variablefix = rent))
```

One option is create a new mean function  with the rent argument being fix or with only one argument and apply the lappy function:

```
 >mean_rent <- function(df){...}
 >lapply(df, mean_rent)
```

But, I want a way to use the apply function directly in only one line

Some ideas?

Comment: If you will use the function with only one column with just don't use `v <- df[, "var"]` ?. I am asking so because you said "one column". Of course with the intent of select multiple columns my question is useless.

Comment: `jj<-list(mtcars,mtcars)`; `lapply(1:length(jj),function(j)mean(jj[[j]][,"mpg"],na.rm=TRUE))`

Comment: @user227710 I would use `sapply` instead of `lapply` to get a vector of means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question One: you can also use the names (i.e a character string) or a variable containing the name to index data.frames (and vectors,matrices etc.), so you just have to do:

```
myfun<- function(df, var) {
   # select the column
   v <- df[,var]

   # rest of function
}
```

but it is more common to define the function on a vector and then just call it with myfun(df[,var])

Question Two: Instead of assigning the new function to a variable, you can also just pass it on directly, i.e.

```
lapply(list_of_dfs, function(df){ mean( df$rent ) })
```